# How to generate a key pair to support Ethereum accounts?

Tags: ethereum, erc20

I am planning to create my own HD wallet to support ERC 20 standard token, I am generating the seed using the javascript bitcore-mnemonics plugin. Now I want to generate a private key, public key and address from my generate 12 words mnemonics using javascript. How I can achieve this, I need help?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly query your node, i.e., Parity with `parity_newAccountFromPhrase` - it accepts seeds like bitcore-mnemonics:

```
curl --data '{"method":"parity_newAccountFromPhrase","params":["stylus outing overhand dime radial seducing harmless uselessly evasive tastiness eradicate imperfect","hunter2"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

I give you the answer with `curl` as you did not specify what exactly you are looking for, but JSONRPC wrappers should be available for all majore programming languages.

[Reference](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity_accounts-module#parity_newaccountfromphrase).

Comment: Thanks for your time,I am using JavaScript,and i just want to know,how i can check my generated private key,public key and address the format is valid